# Disabling a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button

I need help trying to make my button disable after it has been clicked, any help would be grateful and if you need anymore information just ask me, Thanks! any help will be appreciated.

```
function addGame() 
{
    var side = $("#side").val();
    var steamid = $("#steamid").val();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    var buttonText = document.getElementById('createGameButton').innerHTML;

    if(buttonText=='Are you sure?')
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'addGame.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: 'side=' + side + '&steamid=' + steamid + '&amount=' + amount, 
            dataType: 'text', 
            success: function (data) 
            {
                document.getElementById('game-alert').innerHTML = data;
                $("#game-alert").fadeIn();
                refreshGames();
                document.getElementById('createGameButton').innerHTML = 'Create Game';
            }
        });
    }

    if(buttonText=='Create Game')
    {
        document.getElementById('createGameButton').innerHTML = 'Are you sure?';
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Calvin just put your code to jsFiddle.

Comment: improve the block code format and also added some candidate tags

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#createGameButton" ).prop( "disabled", true );
```

Comment: I have added this code and it has not disabled my button, have any other ideas on how to fix it? thanks :)

Comment: document.getElementById('createGameButton').disabled = true

Comment: <div class="text-center">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-success" id="createGameButton" onclick="addGame();">Create Coinflip</a>
   </div>

Comment: That is the html of the button

Comment: It's not a button, it's an anchor so obviously the code for disabled button won't work

Comment: Is there anyway to get a code that will work with it?

Comment: I have created a plnkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8Kc99cShNDAkcKSmWeW?p=preview